# What are these UITableView lines in the image?

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView on a UIView.  This UIView is in a UICollectionViewCell which means that I can do the action you can see in the image. A new UICollectionViewCell is coming on from the right.  As a new cell comes onto the visible rect it is slightly resized you can see that the right one is slightly smaller.

While this new cell is "sliding on" the table view has some black lines that show through.  It is not the actual separator lines as you can clearly see them, further turning them off or making them the same colour as the cell does not change things.

So can anyone tell me what these black lines are and if I can either directly get rid of them or cover them over somehow.

[image]

Comment: Seriously Nobody knows what they are?  Is this magic Apple pixie dust?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the lines are cell separators. You could set the [separatorStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) property to [UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: Thanks Bogus, but in my question I did say that I had tried that.  I have tried setting the style to none as well as setting the colour to the same as the cell.

Comment: Seriously Nobody knows what they are?  Is this magic Apple pixie dust?